# I cannot use multiple classes in IntelliJ

Tags: java

I recently started learning Java from w3schools and I am using IntelliJ. Right now I've just begun learning OOP and I wanted to test one example from the w3schools tutorial inside IntelliJ, using multiple classes. So we have two classes, Main and Second , and we have to use the object x from class Main inside the class second, [like in the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0OMU.png) , but when I try to run, i have this Error: Main method not found in class com.company.Main, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Below you can see the [Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OR99.png) and the [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgAaF.png) class. Any information would be useful. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as images. Also post the entire execution command that you're using, because the error is clearly saying you're trying to run the `Main` class when you should be running the `Second` class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Running test from `Second` class will fix your issue.

[image]